# Acessing List items on another class

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I would like to know how can I access the items of a list on a different class where the list was created.Particularly i want to access items of the restaurantList on the Restaurant Screen class.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:projectfooddelivery/Src/models/restaurant.dart';


List<Restaurant> restaurantList=[
  Restaurant(image:"kfcloja.jpg",distance: "2 miles away",location:"Shoprite do magoanine",restaurantName: "KFC"),
  Restaurant(image:"dominos.jpg",distance: "0.9 miles away",location:"Downtown",restaurantName: "Dominos"),
  Restaurant(image:"kfclogo.png",distance: "2 miles away",location:"Shoprite do magoanine",restaurantName: "KFC"),

];//I would like to access the items on the list
class RestaurantWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 350,
      child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemCount: restaurantList.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Container(

                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                        width: 1.0,
                        color: Colors.grey[100]

                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
                ),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                        width: 150,
                        child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            child: Image.asset("images/${restaurantList[index].image}",fit:BoxFit.cover ,)
                        )
                    ),

                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                        height: 70,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text("${restaurantList[index].restaurantName}",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Icon(Icons.star,size: 15,color:Colors.yellowAccent,),
                                Icon(Icons.star,size: 15,color:Colors.yellowAccent),
                                Icon(Icons.star,size: 15,color:Colors.yellowAccent),
                                Icon(Icons.star,size: 15,color:Colors.yellowAccent),
                                Icon(Icons.star_half,size: 15,color:Colors.yellowAccent),

                              ],
                            ),
                            Text("${restaurantList[index].location}"),
                            Text("${restaurantList[index].distance}"),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
    );


  }
}
```

In this class

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:projectfooddelivery/Src/widgets/menu_widget.dart';
import 'package:smooth_star_rating/smooth_star_rating.dart';

class RestaurantScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: 400,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset(
                  "images/kfcloja.jpg",
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                Positioned(
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_left,size: 40,color: Colors.white,),
                    onPressed: (){},
                  ),
                  top: 15,

                )
              ],
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 14, left: 14, right: 14),
              child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "Restaurant KFC",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 18,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "0.2 miles away",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: SmoothStarRating(
                        allowHalfRating: false,
                        starCount: 5,
                        size: 20.0,
                        filledIconData: Icons.blur_off,
                        halfFilledIconData: Icons.blur_on,
                        color: Colors.yellowAccent,
                        borderColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
                        spacing: 0.0),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: Text("200 Main St, New york"),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 30, right: 30, top: 20, bottom: 5),
                    child: Container(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          FlatButton.icon(
                            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            ),
                            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.rate_review,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            label: Text(
                              'Reviews',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {},
                          ),
                          FlatButton.icon(
                            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            ),
                            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.contact_phone,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            label: Text(
                              'Contact',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {},
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                     Text(
                      "Menu",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                     MenuWidget(),


                ],
              )
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to open `RestaurantScreen` from `RestaurantWidget`?

Comment: so its impossible right???

Comment: if I make the list on the Restaurant Screen I can access it from RestaurantWidget???

Comment: @ValdoAmaral Please check the below solution and let me know in case of concern

Comment: Is possible. Check Ravindra's answer.

Comment: @ValdoAmaral Have you checked the solution, If it workable for you then please accept the asnwer for the future users. I have created the demo example with it, please check and let me know

Comment: @ValdoAmaral have you checked the below solution

Comment: @ValdoAmaral Any update on below solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You can send and receive the data from one screen to another as follow , you need to use the `Navigator` for it , In below example i am sending the data from class **A** to class **B** as follow

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => B(bean: restaurantList[index])), //// HERE B IS THE CLASS ON WHICH YOU NEED TO CARRY DATA FROM CLASS A
);
```

And inside the **B** class you need to create the contrsutor to receive the data from **A** like below

```
class B extends StatefulWidget {
  Restaurant bean;

  B ({Key key, @required this.bean}) : super(key: key); ////YOU WILL GET THE DATA HERE FROM THE CONSTRUCTOR , AND USE IT INSIDE THE CLASS LIKE "widget.bean" 

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _B();
  }
}
```

And please check the example of it to pass data from one class to another

> **A class** which send data to **B** class

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

import 'B.dart';
import 'Fields.dart';

    class A extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        // TODO: implement createState
        return _A();
      }
    }

    class _A extends State<A> {

      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            title: 'Screen A',
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            theme: ThemeData(
              primaryColor: Colors.red,
              accentColor: Color(0xFFFEF9EB),
            ),
            home: Scaffold(
                appBar: new AppBar(),
                body: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: Text("Screen A"),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: fields.length,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                              return ListTile(
                                title: new Text("Rating #${fields[index].rating}"),
                                subtitle: new Text(fields[index].title),
                                onTap: (){

                                  Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => B(bean: fields [index])), //// HERE B IS THE CLASS ON WHICH YOU NEED TO CARRY DATA FROM CLASS A
                                  );
                                },
                              );
                            }),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )));
      }
    }

    List<Fields> fields = [
      new Fields(
        'One',
        1,
      ),
      new Fields(
        'Two',
        2,
      ),
      new Fields(
        'Three',
        3,
      ),
      new Fields(
        'Four',
        4,
      ),
      new Fields(
        'Five',
        5,
      ),
    ];
```

> Now check **B** class which receive the data from **A** class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'Fields.dart';


    class B extends StatefulWidget{

      Fields bean;

      B ({Key key, @required this.bean}) : super(key: key); ////YOU WILL GET THE DATA HERE FROM THE CONSTRUCTOR , AND USE IT INSIDE THE CLASS LIKE "widget.bean"

      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        // TODO: implement createState
         return _B ();

      }

    }

    class _B extends State<B> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // TODO: implement build
        return MaterialApp(
            title: 'Screen A',
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            theme: ThemeData(
              primaryColor: Colors.red,
              accentColor: Color(0xFFFEF9EB),
            ),
            home: Scaffold(
                appBar: new AppBar(),
                body: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text("Screen B" ,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),),
                        )
                      ),
                       Text("Rating=>>>  ${widget.bean.rating}  and Title ${widget.bean.title} ")
                    ],
                  ),
                )));
      }
    }
```

And I have used the Pojo class for the list ,please check it once

> **Fields.dart**

```
class Fields {
  final String title;
  final int rating;

  Fields(this.title, this.rating);
}
```

> And the output of the above program as follow.

[image]

Comment: @ValdoAmaral  If it is workable for you then please mark answer right and upvote it